# Ubuntu 16.04 Missing CUPS file

Tags: printing, files, canon

Within System Settings my printer (Canon MG3150) is indicating that there is a missing CUPS file (File "/usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertogutenprint.5.2" not available: No such file or directory), and I am no longer able to send print jobs to the printer. This problem has only occurred after upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04 from Ubuntu 15.10. Where can I obtain the missing file, and can it simply be 'pasted' into the 'filter' folder/directory ?

Mo

Comment: It is part of the package `printer-driver-gutenprint`. If you don't have that package (check with `apt-cache policy printer-driver-gutenprint`), install it and try again.